# am using a php with xampp, to connect to check my work

Tags: php

Hello I am using a php with xampp, to connect to check my work, and it works fine but when i use's my real server domain host, to check if is working fine and I get this error (Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in)

Here is my code: please anyone could help me for what i did wrong on this:

```
<?php



if ($user) {
    if ($password) {
        require("connect.php");

        $password = md5(md5("agdagsjagsj".$password."77gggg77g7g7g"));

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $dbid = $row['id'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];         
            $dbactive = $row['active'];

            if ($password == $dbpass) {
                if($dbactive == 1) {

                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                    header("Location: ./processing.php");

                    }
                    else
                        echo "Your account is not active you need to activate your account. $form";

                }
                else
                    echo "Your Password is incorrect. $form";

        }
        else
            echo "Your Username is not listed in our database. $form";

        mysql_close();


    }
    else 
        echo "You enter no password. $form";


    }
    else

        echo "Please enter your username. $form";


}
else
}
?>
```

Comment: There’s a lot of things that could be improved with that code. Firstly, don’t use the `mysql_*` functions; they’re deprecated (use the MySQLi or PDO extension instead). Also, a password hashed twice with `md5()` isn’t too secure. You should be hashing them using the Blowfish algorith; take a look at the [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function.

Comment: Try to read php [documantation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-num-rows.php) after read about php data [type resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

Comment: What is the value of the $user variable? As the prev commenter said, your code is very vunerable. Use mysql_real_escape_string at least.

Comment: is your db username and password correct is it even connecting to the DB?

Comment: whats ur php version in hosting and local ? did you take a look at the configuration values like db name, password, host etc

Comment: @mazraara i try to check if my db is connecting with this variable die ("could not connect"); and it appears as instructed, why my db is not connecting i try this several times, and when i use xampp it works fine, any help what to do maybe on my host

Comment: please post the connect.php code

Comment: the fact is i trying implement it also as the same to the xampp and it says could not connect but when i remove it connects maybe i didn't set the variable die correctly

Comment: my phpmyadmin version is 4.0.8

Comment: so there is no help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly possible that your query already failed, you should check it before invoke `mysql_num_rows($query)` (or other stuff such as `mysql_fetch_array($query)`)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
if($query === FALSE) {
    die("error message here"); 
    // add error handling code here
}
else{
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
   ... // your rest of code
}
```

Comment: yes i have check it now and it say  Could not select, as i mentioned in the error message

Comment: so why is not selecting the query

Comment: but with xampp is not echoing the error message which means it works fine with xampp and is selecting but in my host it doesn't and say could not select

Comment: is there nothing to do to help